# How do I export to Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-5

I followed [this guide](https://satishratnaparkhi.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/export-to-excel-using-mvc-4/) which was recommended in another post about this but I can't quite get it to work. I get a 404 error when trying to redirect to /LogModelsController/ExportData which - as I understood it - was what I was supposed to do.

**_LogPartialLayout.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "LogModelsController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("message", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })

            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("timestamp", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("level", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.message)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timeStamp)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.level)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="Export" id="Export" value="Export" />
}
```

[image: _LogPartialLayout.cshtml]

**LogModelsController.cs**

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
        {
            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = db.Log.ToList();
            gv.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Loglist.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return RedirectToAction("~/LogModels/Index");
        }
```

**LogModel.cs**

```
namespace ASDMVC.Models
{
    [Table("Log")]
    public class LogModel
    {
        [Key]
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public int customerId { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public LogDBContext() : base("MySqlConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet <LogModel> Log { get; set; }

    }
}
```

TD;DR: How do I properly export this table to Excel?

*Bonus: Does it work with PagedList too?*

---

### Edit 3 - SOLVED

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "LogModels"))
{
    <input type="submit" name="Export" id="Export" value="Export" />
}
```

**LogModelsController.cs**

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
{
    DataTable dataTable = GetData();

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");
        //true generates headers
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(stream);

        string fileName = "myfilename.xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        stream.Position = 0;
        return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
    }
}

public DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", Session["myID"]);
                comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Log WHERE CustomerId = @val1";
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I made a mistake in the CommandText and put "Id" instead of "CustomerId" - it now returns the entire table in the Excel file.

Comment: The guide doesn't produce an Excel file. Use a library like EPPlus to create a *real* Excel file. Right now you are sending an HTML table masquerading as an old-style (binary) Excel file. Excel will try to *import* this file, using default settings

Comment: It's better to use EPPLUS to export as excel file.

Comment: `Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "LogModels")` Remove the 'controller' part from the route

Comment: @CristiPufu when changing this I actually got a excel file! Awesome! But it only contained the first row of the table. I will update post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guide doesn't show how to create an Excel file, it shows a hack that creates an HTML file with a Table. Excel will try to import csv or HTML files with tables using default settings which can often fail.

It's far easier to create a *proper* Excel file using a library like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/).
I'm sure this has been answered before but I can't find an answer that shows both how to [create an Excel file from data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus)  and set the [proper content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608547/generating-an-excel-file-with-epplus-is-failing) for an `xlsx` file.

EPPlus provides the LoadFromDataTable and LoadFromCollection methods to fill an Excel range with data pulled from a DataTable or generic collection. The column or property names are used as headers respectively.

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
{

    //Somehow, load data to a DataTable

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");
        //true generates headers
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(stream);

        string fileName = "myfilename.xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        stream.Position = 0;
        return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
    }
}
```

LoadFromDataTable or LoadFromCollection return an Excel cell range which can be used to format the table:

```
var range=ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table);
range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
range.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

You can also apply a table style to the range, or pass the desired style to `LoadFromDataTable` or `LoadFromCollection`, eg:

```
ws.Cells[1,1].LoadFromDataTable(table, true, TableStyles.Light1);
```

The library's [Githup wiki](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki) shows how to [format the result](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formatting-and-styling), generate formulas, PivotTables, handle tables etc.

Saving to a MemoryStream may be an issue if you want to create a relatively large sheet. Writing the same data twice, once to the MemoryStream and then copying it to output, wastes cycles. Writing directly to the output stream from an MVC action is a bad practice though. The trick is to create a custom FileResult that handles EPPlus packages and return that instead of the FileResult returned by `File`, eg:

```
public class EpplusResult:FileResult
{
    public EpplusResult(ExcelPackage package)
        : base("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    {
        if (package == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("package");
        }

        Package = package;
    }

    public ExcelPackage Package { get; private set; }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        // grab chunks of data and write to the output stream
        Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
        using (Package)
        {
            Package.SaveAs(outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows you to write the following action:

```
public FileResult ExportData()
{

    ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
    var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");       
    ...
    ws.Cells[1,1].LoadFromDataTable(table, true, TableStyles.Light1);

    return new EpplusResult(package){FileDownloadName = "SomeFile.xlsx"};
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try then, reporting back as fast as I can :)

Comment: I have updated the post to reflect changes made after your suggestion, I'm fairly new to this so thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create HTML based excel files, they have so many problems.

Insteed use a compact library for that such as [epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
{

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("LogMessages");
       //Headers
        ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Message";
        ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "TimeStamp";
        ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Level";


       var rowNumber=1;

        foreach (var log in DbContext.Log)
       {
           ws.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = vehicle.message;
           ws.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = vehicle.timeStamp;
           ws.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = vehicle.level;
           rowNumber++;
       }


        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(stream);

        string fileName = "logMessags.xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        stream.Position = 0;
        return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
    }
}
```

I have used Panagiotis Kanavos code structure to implement this solution

Comment: This answer has problems. The OP is creating HTML files, not "XML based" files. EPPlus creates XLSX files which *are* zipped XML

Comment: I have edit my answer, I know it doesn't really answer the question but I have used HTML before for creating excel files and it had so many problems with cell formating, types, colors etc.

Comment: The linked article is a bit convoluted. In fact, it's far easier to create a sheet from a collection or DataTable, simply by calling `LoadFromDataTable` or `LoadFromCollection`, as shown [in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus). The OP should also set the correct content type, as shown in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608547/generating-an-excel-file-with-epplus-is-failing). This question could be marked as a duplicate of these two if it were possible.

Comment: I will have a look at all those links asap!

Comment: I have looked at all those links and it doesn't seem very applicable to my problem and would requite some big changes in the code to make this work if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @DanAndersson the CodeProject article is a bit convoluted as it's trying to show off the libraries abilities. *Your* code doesn't produce an Excel file though and *has* to be changed. Generating a simple Excel file with EPPlus takes less than 10 lines though, as shown in my answer.

Comment: This might be a working solution as well. But for now I will stick with the solution I've updated in the post. Big thanks tho and I will upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, This library is containing an ExcelResult that will automate the process of creation, and send Excel file to the client by calling Excel() method just like Json().

https://github.com/iabdelkareem/MVC-Excel-Extensions