# Html table convert as excel and send via email

Tags: c#, excel, email, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing an app which can generate a excel file using html table. Up to now I developed html table download as excel file part. (This happens in client side with javascript). Now I need to send email with that attachment (The excel file) to particular person's email address. So I'm confuse how to do this, because up to now I generate excel in client side and need to send that file via email. In this case is it needed to copy client side excel to the server? If so how to do this?
Please give me a direction.

> **Update 1 (Adding codes)**

This is the javascript, that I used to download html table as excel to client side.

```
    var tablesToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
          + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
          + '<Styles>'
          + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
          + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
          + '</Styles>'
          + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
        , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
        , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
            var ctx = "";
            var workbookXML = "";
            var worksheetsXML = "";
            var rowsXML = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
                if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
                for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
                    rowsXML += '<Row>'
                    for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
                        var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
                        var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
                        var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
                        dataValue = (dataValue) ? dataValue : tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
                        var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
                        dataFormula = (dataFormula) ? dataFormula : (appname == 'Calc' && dataType == 'DateTime') ? dataValue : null;
                        ctx = {
                            attributeStyleID: (dataStyle == 'Currency' || dataStyle == 'Date') ? ' ss:StyleID="' + dataStyle + '"' : ''
                               , nameType: (dataType == 'Number' || dataType == 'DateTime' || dataType == 'Boolean' || dataType == 'Error') ? dataType : 'String'
                               , data: (dataFormula) ? '' : dataValue
                               , attributeFormula: (dataFormula) ? ' ss:Formula="' + dataFormula + '"' : ''
                        };
                        rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
                    }
                    rowsXML += '</Row>'
                }
                ctx = { rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i };
                worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
                rowsXML = "";
            }

            ctx = { created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML };
            workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

            var link = document.createElement("A");
            link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
            link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
            link.target = '_blank';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    })();
```

Still I do not have idea to save generated excel to server and send it as email.

Comment: Don't. HTML tables are *NOT* Excel. Use a library like EPPlus to create a *real* Excel file. It's as easy as `sheet.LoadFromCollection()` or `sheet.LoadFromDataTable()`

Comment: Seems yes - you need to copy your generated document to server as client script do has access to your storage and can't attach document to your mail

Comment: Using HTML tables is an ugly hack going around that saves HTML tables with a fake xlsx extension. Excel isn't fooled, it recognizes the HTML file and *tries* to import the data using defaults. This will easily break for any number of reasons, eg different locale settings for decimals and dates.

Comment: @VadimB not at all. There's *no* reason to use HTML tables, or use any kind of script. It's easy to create an Excel file in a MemoryStream and use that to create the attachment.

Comment: *Why* are you doing this in JavaScript when you use ASP.NET MVC5? That's not an HTML table but it's *not* an XLSX file either, it's the intermediate XML format that was used briefly with Excel 2003.

Comment: Agree with you @PanagiotisKanavos, but we do not know business scenario - if here table is fully dynamic and user able to configure and fill data on web page before generating document. So this depend on equirenments.

Comment: Yap. With client side the user is able to show/hide columns. Actually it is applied jquery datatable for html table. Only selected columns need to export as excel. that is the reason I used above javascript for export html table as excel.

Comment: @weeraa just remove the columns on the server side then, eg `MyTable.Columns.Remove`. Or use a library that creates real xlsx files like `js-xlsx` and create an xlsx file from an existing HTML table

Answer (score 1):

AS per our discussion:
1. you need to send data from client to server
you can use this code to do this sending headers and values to server using ajax and you can also filter columns as you want

```
function SaveToServer() {
        var gov = GetHeaders('tbl');

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/ReciveData")',
            data: { headers: JSON.stringify(gov.heasers), data: JSON.stringify(gov.data) },
            success: function (data) {
         // Success
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
            }
        });

    }

    function GetHeaders(tableName) {

        table = document.getElementById(tableName);
        var tbl_Hdata = [];
        var tbl_Data = [];
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            var rowData = [];
            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                // add column filter
                if (i == 0) {
                    tbl_Hdata.push(col.innerHTML);
                }
                else {
                    rowData.push(col.innerHTML);
                }
            }
            if (i > 0) {
                tbl_Data.push(rowData);
            }
        }

        return { heasers: tbl_Hdata, data: tbl_Data };
    }
```

2. now we want to recive this data and convert it to datatable to save it to excel in server side
   using NPOI

   ```
   public void ReciveData(string headers, string data)
   {
       #region Read Data
       List<string> tbl_Headers = new List<string>();
       List<List<string>> tbl_Data = new List<List<string>>();
       tbl_Headers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(headers);
       tbl_Data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(data);
       #endregion

       #region Create Data Table
       DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Data");
       foreach (var prop in tbl_Headers)
       {
           dataTable.Columns.Add(prop);
       }
       DataRow row;
       foreach (var rw in tbl_Data)
       {
           row = dataTable.NewRow();

           for (int i = 0; i < rw.Count; i++)
           {
               row[tbl_Headers[i]] = rw[i];
           }
           dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
       }
       #endregion

       #region Save To excel
       string path = @"D:\";
       string fileName = "";
       GenerateExcelSheetWithoutDownload(dataTable, path, out fileName); 
       #endregion

   }

   public bool GenerateExcelSheetWithoutDownload(DataTable dataTable, string exportingSheetPath, out string exportingFileName)
   {
       #region Validate the parameters and Generate the excel sheet
       bool returnValue = false;
       exportingFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xls";

       if (dataTable != null && dataTable.Rows.Count > new int())
       {
           string excelSheetPath = string.Empty;
           #region Check If The directory is exist
           if (!Directory.Exists(exportingSheetPath))
           {
               Directory.CreateDirectory(exportingSheetPath);
           }

           excelSheetPath = exportingSheetPath + exportingFileName;
           FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(excelSheetPath);
           #endregion

           #region Write stream to the file
           MemoryStream ms = DataToExcel(dataTable);
           byte[] blob = ms.ToArray();
           if (blob != null)
           {
               using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(blob))
               {
                   FileStream fs = new FileStream(excelSheetPath, FileMode.Create);
                   inStream.WriteTo(fs);
                   fs.Close();
               }
           }
           ms.Close();
           returnValue = true;
           #endregion
       }

       return returnValue;
       #endregion
   }

   private static MemoryStream DataToExcel(DataTable dt)
   {
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       using (dt)
       {

           #region Create File
           HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();//Create an excel Workbook
           ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("data");//Create a work table in the table

           int RowHeaderIndex = new int();
           #endregion

           #region Table Headers
           IRow headerTableRow = sheet.CreateRow(RowHeaderIndex);
           if (dt != null)
           {
               foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
               {
                   headerTableRow.CreateCell(column.Ordinal).SetCellValue(column.Caption);
               }
               RowHeaderIndex++;
           }
           #endregion

           #region Data

           foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
           {
               IRow dataRow = sheet.CreateRow(RowHeaderIndex);
               foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
               {
                   dataRow.CreateCell(column.Ordinal).SetCellValue(row[column].ToString());
               }
               RowHeaderIndex++;
           }
           #endregion

           workbook.Write(ms);
           ms.Flush();
           //ms.Position = 0;
       }
       return ms;
   }
   ```
3. Now you can send this file as attachment in mail

Answer (score 0):

You can't create Excel files with HTML tables. This is a hack that's used to fake actual Excel files. Excel isn't fooled, it recognizes the HTML file and tries to import the data using defaults. This will easily break for any number of reasons, eg different locale settings for decimals and dates.

Excel files are just zipped XML files. You can create them using XML manipulation, the Open XML SDK or a library like EPPlus.

Creating an Excel file with EPPlus is as easy as calling the `LoadFromCollection` or `LoadFromDatatable` method. The sheet can be saved to any stream, including FileStream or MemoryStream. A MemoryStream can be used to send the data to a web browser as [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837808/how-do-i-export-to-excel/32838151#32838151):

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
{

    //Somehow, load data to a DataTable

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");
        //true generates headers
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(stream);

        string fileName = "myfilename.xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        stream.Position = 0;
        return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
    }
}
```

Mail attachments can also be created from a MemoryStream. The [Attachment(Stream, string,string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ds708xx(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) constructor accepts any stream as input. The example above could be modified to create an attachment instead of sending the data to the browser:

```
public void SendData(string server, string recipientList)
{

    //Same as before
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(stream);

        string fileName = "myfilename.xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        stream.Position = 0;
        SendExcel(server,recipientList);
    }
}

void SendExcel(string server, string recipientList)
{
        //Send the file
        var message = new MailMessage("logMailer@contoso.com", recipientList);
        message.Subject = "Some Data";
        Attachment data = new Attachment(stream, name, contentType);
        // Add the attachment to the message.
        message.Attachments.Add(data);
        // Send the message.
        // Include credentials if the server requires them.
        var client = new SmtpClient(server);
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Generating an XSLX table on the client side becomes a lot easier if you use a library like [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). There's even a sample that [generates an XLSX file from an HTML table](http://sheetjs.com/demos/table.html)

Comment: Actually this is what. I create html table as jquery datatable. With my above javascript code, I generate excel file. With client side, the user is able to reduce or add (There is option to do this in jquery datatable) number of columns as his/her need. (When getting data from the server, it is load all columns initially) It might display 10 columns initially and user needs just 5 columns. So he/she needs to save required 5 columns excel sheet. As same as I need to send this via email. Seems your example cannot remove or add columns. That is why I try to export excel from html table.

Comment: Why can't you remove columns? You can remove columns directly from a DataTable - just call [Columns.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5tda838(v=vs.110).aspx). A collection can be the result of a LINQ Select query which selects the columns you need. In both cases you can use a changing set of columns.