# .NET Core API Read data from Couchbase and return response as a file stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, couchbase

I want to create an API endpoint that returns a file as a stream. The data is available in Couchbase, so my requirement is to read data from Couchbase and return as a file stream.

I'm currently considering `FileStreamResult` but I do not want to load the whole data set into memory and then return it as a stream. Reading data from Couchbase and Returning data as a file stream should happen parallelly. Just wondering what would be the best approach to handle this.

Comment: That's precisely what `FileStreamResult` is for. To copy data from some stream, eg the stream returned from Couchbase to the response stream. *Do* you get the data from Couchbase as a stream though?

Comment: BTW what do you mean *stream*? Stream as in a class that inherits from Stream or stream as in start sending results immediatelly without waiting for everything to become available? Or streaming as in retrieve N1QL results with `UseStreaming()` and copy them to the response?

Comment: Stream as in, I'm getting data from Couchbase in a loop and planing to convert that result into memory stream and send to `FileStreamResult `. If im not mistaken, `FileStreamResult` cannot accept dynamic streams right? as in it's not possible to add more content to stream once we passed it to `FileStreamResult ` yeah?

Comment: you are using the wrong word then. FileStreamResult works with streams just fine. Streams are dynamic *by definition*. They can return *anything* at any time and contain any amount of data. You don't have a stream though.

Comment: Post your code. You *can* write to the response output stream (that's a *real* stream) whenever you want, eg inside a loop, although directly writing to it should be considered a worst-case scenario. You can convert your results to an IEnumerable<T> which is what you call `streaming` and have ASP.NET Core API serialize it, but that would be a little tricky - serialization happens *after* the action method returns so your source/query would have to be available even after the action terminates

Comment: You could create your own custom [ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0) that includes the query code, serializes when asked to and disposes of any connections when finished, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32838151/134204). In that case, the results were needed as a file so the custom ActionResult implemented `FileResult`

Comment: You should probably inherit from [JsonResult](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonResult.cs). Looking at the code eventually it uses a JSON.NET serializer to write whatever value you pass to it, including IEnumerable<T>. Perhaps you could even use `return Json(myResultsIterator)` if you can convert your loop to an iterator method. Post your code!

Comment: Could you please elaborate the last statement a bit more. I still don't have a proper implementation to post. Would be really great if you could provide some code snippet.