# How to create a csv file with bold header row using C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a csv file with bold header text.This following code is creating one header row.But i want this header in bold style.

```
       'Add Response header 

    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv", "check_"))
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.csv"

    Try
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        'Add Header  dr.GetName(count)     

        For count As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            If GridView1.Columns(count) IsNot Nothing Then
                sb.Append(GridView1.Columns(count).HeaderText)
            End If
            If count < GridView1.Columns.count - 1 Then
                sb.Append(",")
            End If
        Next
        Response.Write(sb.ToString() + vbLf)
        Response.Flush()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Response.[End]()
```

Comment: A csv file is in ASCII format: there is no style, only text: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: CSV files are plaintext, so they don't contain any formatting. Some programs (e.g. Excel) may interpret the first line as a header, but this is entirely a function of the program.

Answer (score 4):

CSV is plain text seperated by commas (,)

There is no styling attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, a CSV is just text without formatting.

Since i'm assuming that you want the bold header in excel and you're exporting an ASP.NET `GridView` to a CSV file, there are two other options:

1. Render the `GridView`'s HTML(a HTML-Table) with a bold header to a file, excel will interpret it correctly
2. Create a real excel file, i can recommend [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439) warmly, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574414/284240)'s a sample.

Sample for the first approach:

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Contacts.xls";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

If you run the code as above, it will result in an `HttpException` as follows:

> Control 'GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form
>   tag with runat=server."

To avoid this error, add the following code:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    // yes, it's correct that this is empty
}
```

Comment: if i am running on local iis then your code is working not on server.

Comment: Please define "not working", do you get any exceptions, have you debugged to see what happens?

Comment: yes i tried ,program is executing successfully without error message but in csv file data is not coming.

Comment: @user1307302: Try to load the GridView DataSource and DataBind it before you call `GridView1.RenderControl(htw);`.