# Send ExcelPackage file to user

Tags: asp.net, excel, file

I want to build `ExcelPackage` file on server side and than send allow user to download it.
Here is my code for file creating:

```
private byte[] ExcelFileCreate()
        {
            using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = User.Identity.Name;
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Skybot";
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Company = "Dataminds";

                excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Selected unit folder");
                var excelWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                excelWorksheet.Name = "Selected unit folder";

                int rowIndex = 1;
                int columnIndex = 1;

                do
                {
                    var cell = excelWorksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex];
                    var fill = cell.Style.Fill;
                    fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);
                    columnIndex++;
                } while (columnIndex != 4);


                excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "action cell";
                excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "time cell";
                excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "processor cell";
                excelWorksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "action cell";
                excelWorksheet.Cells[2, 2].Value = "time cell";
                excelWorksheet.Cells[2, 3].Value = "processor cell";

                return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
            }
        }
```

And send it you user:

variant 1:

```
private void FileTransfer(byte[] fileBytes)
        {
            //Clear the response               
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Cookies.Clear();
            //Add the header & other information      
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            Response.CacheControl = "private";
            Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
            Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "cache");
            Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "60");
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; " +
            "filename=\"ExcelReport.xlsx\"; " +
            "size=" + fileBytes.Length.ToString() + "; " +
            "creation-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R") + "; " +
            "modification-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R") + "; " +
            "read-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            //Write it back to the client    
            Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
            Response.End();

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
            Response.End();
        }
```

variant 2:

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
    Response.End();
```

variant 3:

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileBytes));

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
    Response.End();
```

And none of them works.
There is no pop-up window with suggestion to store/open file.

Event handler that should make it works:

```
protected void TreeViewUnit_OnContextMenuItemClick(object sender, 
      RadTreeViewContextMenuEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    FileTransfer(ExcelFileCreate());
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: did  you tried ***variant 1*** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelReport.xlsx");
Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
Response.End();
```

It works for me as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574414/284240).

Comment: Does not work.
It saves on local disk fine with  File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Reports\Report.xlsx, excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());

Comment: It works on Page_Load() but does not on event handler call inside ajax panel.

Comment: Have a look: http://encosia.com/ajax-file-downloads-and-iframes/ Are you in a full- or async-postback? You need a full postback, you can use a [`PostBacktrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx) therefore.