# ASP.NET Export DataView to Excel 2010 format issue

Tags: asp.net, excel, .net-3.5, export, dataview

I'm working on exporting DataView object to Excel file sample.

My solution is just a simple Download.aspx page with one override function:

*The ASPX.CS file:*

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export2excel.xls");
    DataView view = (DataView) Session["MyView"];
    exportGrid.DataSource = view;
    exportGrid.DataBind();
    exportGrid.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

*The ASPX file:*

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <asp:DataGrid id="exportGrid" style="Z-INDEX: 101; LEFT: 16px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 16px"
        runat="server" CssClass="dgDefault" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EFF7D3"></AlternatingItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#FF0000"></HeaderStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Comment"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact"></asp:BoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
</form>
```

The solution works fine. There is Excel file, well-formated. But one thing, MS Excel 2007 and 2010 always throw a message before opening them.

**The root cause is because we are opening a HTML file as an XLS file** (render using HTMLTextWriter) that scares Office 2007 and later. If you open the export2excel.xls file using notepad++, you will see its HTML.

Someone suggests asking people to change the regedit on client side to disable its Security. You guys know this is not our option, isn't it?

> Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security
>   Value: (DWORD)"ExtensionHardening" = [0 = Disable check; 1 = Enable
>   check and prompt; 2 = Enable check, no prompt deny open] Default
>   setting if value not present is 1 (enable and prompt).

**QUESTION:** Is there another way around to export to Excel file that will make MS Excel 2007 and later peacefully open them? Without prompting an annoying message box?

Comment: Use an excel library like `EPPlus` instead of a HTML table. It's simple as `ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(data, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light1);` then. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9574414/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter yeah, it's good solution in actual case. But this is just a demo so I'm trying (yup, trying to see how far I can go) to keep it simple (without using any library). Thanks!